# Unsupported type <(class 'pandas.core.frame.DateFrame'> in write()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to output 2 columns to an excel sheet with the below code and got an syntax error. How to fix this? Thanks.

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('sheet1')

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]},columns=['A','B'])
col=['A','B']
df[col]
text_format = workbook.add_format({ 'align': 'left', 'fg_color': 'blue', 'bold':True})

worksheet.write(7,5,df[col],text_format)
workbook.save()
```

Comment: What is a `pd.Dataframe`? Shouldn't it be `pd.DataFrame`? Please post the actual code.

Comment: This’s the actual code

Comment: There are too many problems with the code for me to trust that this is the actual code that you are running. 1) `import xlswriter` should be `import xlsxwriter`. 2) `pd.Dataframe` should be `pd.DataFrame`. Clearly this is not the actual code.

Comment: Those are the typo because I can’t paste anything on stack overflow website using company’s computer. Beside the typo, these are the actual codes. The problem is the worksheet.write() did not run and threw me an error. I tired to figure out why.

Comment: I fixed all the typo you pointed out. Do you happen to know why I got this syntax error ?

Comment: Are you trying to write the whole dataframe into a single cell of the worksheet?

Comment: I want to write the whole dataframe on the worksheet with specific format, alignment and color to specific cells.

Comment: I guess I got it. The write() is for single cell

Comment: Yes, it's for one cell. You could use `write_row()` and iterate over the dataframe.

Comment: How can I output the column value in the df with write_row or write_col ? May I ask for an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `xlsxwriter` can not output an entire `DataFrame` object. You can do one of two things:

- use `xlsxwriter` as an excel writer and call `df.to_excel()` to create the file. You would not be able to achieve the same positioning or formatting, although, you could open the XLSX file afterwards and modify the formatting then.
- iterate over the `DataFrame` and call `write_column()` for each column of data. Something like this should work:

  ```
  import xlsxwriter
  import pandas as pd

  workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('sheet1')

  df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]}, columns=['A','B'])

  text_format = workbook.add_format({'align': 'left', 'bold': True})
  header_format = workbook.add_format({'align': 'left', 'fg_color': 'blue', 'bold': True})

  start_row = 7
  start_col = 5
  worksheet.write_row(start_row, start_col, df.columns, header_format)
  for i, column in enumerate(df.columns, start=start_col):
      worksheet.write_column(start_row+1, i, df[column], text_format)

  workbook.close()
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In this case, I only want the column header to have blue background, all value should not have color background. How could I modify that ?

Comment: Updated answer to provide different header and data cell formats.

Comment: @user032020L no worries.